# How can I repeatedly match from A until B in VIM?

Tags: vim, design-patterns, match

I need to get all text between `<Annotation>` and `</Annotation>`, where a word `MATCH` occurs. How can I do it in VIM?

```
<Annotation about="MATCH UNTIL </Annotation>   " timestamp="0x000463e92263dd4a" href="     5raS5maS90ZWh0YXZha29rb2VsbWEvbGFza2FyaS8QyrqPk5L9mAI">                                                                        
  <Label name="las" />
  <Label name="_cse_6sbbohxmd_c" />
  <AdditionalData attribute="original_url" value="MATCH UNTIL </Annotation>       " />
</Annotation>
<Annotation about="NO MATCH" href="     Cjl3aWtpLmhlbHNpbmtpLmZpL2Rpc3BsYXkvbWF0aHN0YXRLdXJzc2l0L0thaWtraStrdXJzc2l0LyoQh_HGoJH9mAI">
  <Label name="_cse_6sbbohxmd_c" />
  <Label name="courses" />
  <Label name="kurssit" />
  <AdditionalData attribute="original_url" value="NO MATCH" />
</Annotation>
<Annotation about="MATCH UNTIL </ANNOTATION>     " score="1" timestamp="0x000463e90f8eed5c" href="CiZtYXRoc3RhdC5oZWx     zaW5raS5maS90ZWh0YXZha29rb2VsbWEvKhDc2rv8kP2YAg">
  <Label name="_cse_6sbbohxmd_c" />
  <Label name="exercises_without_solutions" />
  <Label name="tehtäväkokoelma" />
  <AdditionalData attribute="original_url" value="MATCH UNTIL </ANNOTATION>" />
</Annotation>
```

Comment: I assume you want to do this in a way that understands XML, so occurrences of </ANNOTATION> that are not the element ending are not matched by VIM, but are counted as part of the match body?  If so, I don't know if VIM can do XML-aware patttern matching like this.

Comment: Also, I tried to make the formatting of the sample a bit easier to view. I assume the whitespace within the attributes is purposeful and left it there.

Comment: What do you mean by "get all text"?  Highlight it?  Yank it?  Append it to a named buffer?

Comment: jholloway7: I don't know how to append it to a named buffer and to save the highlighted text to a separate file.

Comment: Your XML is invalid. The `<` is not allowed in attribute values.

Comment: Gumbo: I put the </Annotation> to attributes to make the Until-condition more clear. Perhaps, I should have used some other notation. Dunno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it *have to* be done within vim?  Could you cheat, and open a second window where you pipe something into more/less that tells you what line number to go to within vim?

-- edit --

I have never done a multi-line match/search in vi[m].  However, to cheat in another window:

```
perl -n -e 'if ( /<tag/ .. /<\/tag/)' -e '{ print "$.:$_"; }' file.xml | less
```

will show the elements/blocks for "tag" (or other longer matching names), with line numbers, in less, and you can then search for the other text within each block.

Close enough?

-- edit --

within "less", type

```
/MATCH
```

to search for occurrences of MATCH.  On the left margin will be the line number where that instance (within the targeted element/tags) is.

within vi[m], type

```
:n
```

where "n" is the desired line number.

Of course, if what you really wanted to do was some kind of search/yank/replace, it's more complicated.  At that point, awk / perl / ruby (or something similar which meets your tastes ... or xsl?) is really the tool you should be using for the transformation.

Comment: I think something like this will be the only possible answer, as to do this right you need to use an XML parser.

Comment: Where is the MATCH word supposed to be? In the place of ..?

Answer (score 4):

First, a disclaimer: Any attempt to slice and dice XML with regular expressions is fragile; a real XML parser would do better.

The pattern:

```
\(<Annotation\(\s*\w\+="[^"]\{-}"\s\{-}\)*>\)\@<=\(\(<\/Annotation\)\@!\_.\)\{-}"MATCH\_.\{-}\(<\/Annotation>\)\@=
```

Let's break it down...

Group 1 is `<Annotation\(\s*\w\+="[^"]\{-}"\s\{-}\)*>`.  It matches the start-tag of the Attribute element.  Group 2, which is embedded in Group 1, matches an attribute and may be repeated 0 or more times.

Group 2 is `\s*\w\+="[^"]\{-}"\s\{-}`.  Most of these pieces are commonly used; the most unusual is `\{-}`, which means non-greedy repetition (`*?` in Perl-compatible regular expressions).  The non-greedy whitespace match at the end is important for performance; without it, Vim will try every possible way to split the whitespace between attributes between the `\s*` at the end of Group 2 and the `\s*` at the beginning of the next occurrence of Group 2.

Group 1 is followed by `\@<=`.  This is a zero-width positive look-behind.  It prevents the start-tag from being included in the matched text (e.g., for s///).

Group 3 is `\(<\/Annotation\)\@!\_.`.  It includes Group 4, which matches the beginning of the Attribute end-tag.  The `\@!` is a zero-width negative look-ahead and `\_.` matches any character (including newlines).  Together, this groups matches at any character except where the Attribute end-tag starts.  Group 3 is followed by a non-greedy repetition marker `\{-}` so that it matches the smallest block of text before MATCH.  If you were to use `\_.` instead of Group 3, the matched text could include the end-tag of an Annotation element that did *not* include MATCH and continue through into the next Annotation element with MATCH.  (Try it.)

The next bit is straightforward: Find MATCH and a minimal number of other characters before the end-tag.

Group 5 is easy: It's the end tag. `\@=` is a zero-width positive look-ahead, which is included here for the same reason as the `\@<=` for the start-tag.  We have to repeat `<\/Attribute` rather than use `\4` because groups with zero-width modifiers aren't captured.